# Same weight enumerator iff equivalent by permutations and local unitaries

Tags: error-correction, mathematics

A non-entangling gate on $ n $ qubits is an element of the group
$$
N\Big(\bigotimes_{i=1}^n U(2)\Big)=\bigotimes_{i=1}^n U(2) \rtimes S_n 
$$
which is generated by $ U(2) $ acting locally on each qubit as well as all $ SWAP $ gates between qubits.

Let $ C_1,C_2 $ be $ [[n,k,d]] $ quantum codes. In other words, $ n_1=n_2, k_1=k_2,d_1=d_2 $. If $ C_1, C_2 $ are equivalent by non-entangling gates then they have the same weight enumerator.** Is the converse true? That is, if $ C_1,C_2 $ have the same weight enumerator must they be related by a non-entangling gate?

---

Note that the weight enumerator already gives $ d $ (it is the   least degree of a nonzero term in $ B(x)-A(x) $ [enumerators polynomials and distance for a quantum error correcting code](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/29309/enumerators-polynomials-and-distance-for-a-quantum-error-correcting-code), note that $ A(x) $ determines $ B(x) $ by quantum McWilliams identity) and gives $ n-k $ (because $ 2^{n-k}=A(1) $ [Do the coefficients of the weight enumerator polynomial add up to $2^{n-k}$ for any $[\![n,k]\!]$ code?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/30181/do-the-coefficients-of-the-weight-enumerator-polynomial-add-up-to-2n-k-for)) so two different codes on $ n $ qubits with the same weight enumerator must have the same parameters $ [[n,k,d]] $.

---

**For a reference for this fact see top of page 4 in

[Quantum Weight Enumerators](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9612015.pdf)

which in turn refers to the discussion below equation (9) in

[Quantum MacWilliams Identities](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9610040.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There are 16 inequivalent $[[7,1,3]]$ codes but they correspond to only 10 weight enumerators. For reference see https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.1780.pdf.